# Is there a more efficient way to move elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am a pretty big noob to HTML/CSS and I'm building my first project by making a resume. I have all the things I need in HTML and now I am organizing and moving things in CSS. In order to move stuff into the right spot I am pretty much guessing and checking by using top/bottom/left/right and adjusting pixels from a relative position. Is there a more efficient way to be moving things around the page than this?

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.SEE {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.skills {
    position: relative;
    top: 51px;
    left: 34px;
}

.experience {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.education {
    position: relative;
    left: 1150px;
    bottom:51px;
}

img {
height:200px;
width:200px;
position: relative;
bottom:450px;
left:250px;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the HTML it is linked to.

```
<body>
    <h1>My Name</h1>

    <div class='SEE'>
        <h2 class='skills'>Skills</h2>
        <h2 class='experience'>Experience</h2>
        <h2 class='education'>Education</h2>
    </div>

    <div class='context'>
        <p class='Ski'>Skills Stuff</p>
        <p class='Exp'>Experience Stuff</p>
        <p class='Edu'>Education Stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Contact Info</h3>
        <p>Email: blank <br>
        Facebook: blank <br>
        Mobile Phone: blank
        </p>

    </div>

    <img src="blank">
</body>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could post your HTML code also

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? will you show us a sample together with HTML..

Comment: Efficient is relative.  Meaning the goal is to help you learn, if you are learning by doing it this way then continue doing it that way.  Although, I would recommend trying different methods here and there while positioning to get the idea of different ways.  Use relative and absolute positions, use animation to move boxes in and out on the screen, just play around with overflow and display.  If you have a direction question, I think we can better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "position: relative" and top/left/right/bottom to build your layout isn't a good practise. I think it's only justified in a few cases and for minor positioning tweaks.

It won't be able to adapt to different screen sizes properly, and will be difficult to maintain when you want to modify that page in the future.

In your case, I think you are trying to position all three H2 titles in a single horizontal line by using relative postitioning, because otherwise they would be in a vertical line. That's because h1/h2/h3... have "display:block" style by default, which means that content after that element will move below it.

If you want them all in one line, you can set your h2 tags to use "display: inline-block" which won't move next titles to the next line, and will allow you to set a width to each title. That way you will be able to get them in a single line.

Also when applying a style to multiple elements inside a container, you can use a selector for your container followed by another selector for the tag or classes you want to affect:

```
.SEE h2 { display:inline-block; }
```

You can save time and avoid duplicate styles that way

Answer (score 2):

In honesty? Use relative dimensions: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

If you are designing for mobile, check out https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/. You will need some good CSS knowledge before starting this I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform: translate(x, y)` or `translateX()` and `translateY()`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is short for Cascading Style Sheets. Cascading means that every new layer inherits from the previous one. The best way to do your styling is by defining base classes and style them. The next step is to sort your elements inside those base classes.

I think you need to give your body the attribute "position: relative;" and then continue.

Answer (score 0):

CSS have no. of options to control the flow of your content on screen. Most of the time you would be playing with them to get most accurate you can.Here's a video series which I found Most helpful for the beginners. It is by DevTips and it contains info. about positioning, floats & clears, Flexbox (This is pretty nice responsive way to setup your website flow), CSS Units, etc. It's worth to check this series.

---

Here's the Link:
[Devtips: Positioning Tutorial](https://youtu.be/kejG8G0dr5U?list=PLqGj3iMvMa4L731ispRfGAabXeRpM4RL6)